# run an ASP code onclick a link using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

Aright. First let me describe what I want to do.
I've a section on my website that clients comment on articles and they can rate those comments Via + / - links that I used there. When a user rated a comment up or down then that user shouldn't be able to rate for that comment any more.
at the moment I wrote the ASP classic code for above problem but it's a bit slow. because when user click on link the page must reload to add vote.

so, here is my question:
I want to use an Ajax code behind that asp code to prevent Reload page after click on + Or - .
something like this when user didn't voted yet

```
<a onclick='rateup("Comment_ID","user_ID") style="cursor:pointer"> <b> + </b> </a>
```

and then update to this when user rated already:

```
<a onclick='alert("You have Already Rated This Comment")' style='cursor:not-allowed;'><span> > + </span></a>
```

once again I've done with ASP code but want a AJAX :)

Comment: Are you familiar with jQuery? Can you use it?

Comment: I'm not familiar but I can use it. trying to learn it with w3school

Comment: Well, ulluoink gave correct answer try doing it yourself and hopefully he can guide you through this if you need..

Answer (score 0):

in your javascript function rateup() make an ajax call to your classic asp site. implement the necessary function and wehn your done write back a status like "vote successful". then in your javascript function change the onclick event of the .

for all this you better use a javascript framework like jQuery.

example code (jQuery and classic asp):

```
<script>
function rateup(Comment_ID, user_ID) {
    $.post("myAspSite.asp", {ajax: true, act:"rate", direction: "up"}, function(data) {
        if( data === "" ) {
            // here comes the code for changing the onclick o the <a>
            $(#idOfClickedLink).click(function() {
                alert("You have Already Rated This Comment")
            });
        }
    });
}
</script>

<%
if request.form("ajax") = true then
    ' we have an ajax call:
    callback( request.form("act") )
else
    ' normal page processing
    call main
end if

function callback(act)
    select case act
        case "voteup"
            ' do the voteup stuff
            response.write ""
        case "votedown"
            ' do the votedown stuff
            response.write ""
    end select
end function

' "normal" page:    
function main

end function
%>
```

Comment: thanks for your time mate. it seems helpful but sadly I'm have less knowledge about jQuery. but I've read w3school examples to learn it. can you please explain me what does {ajax: true, act:"rate", direction: "up"}, function(data) doing :S

Comment: @user885899 that are the parameters for the post request. just like you are submitting a normal html form via post. have a look at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/